# Why conda doesn't remove packages for removed environment?

Tags: anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I am not an expert in informatics stuffs. I deleted an environment that had many packages, one of them psi4 using the command:

```
conda remove --name myenv --all
```

However, in the folder:

```
~/anaconda3/pkgs
```

there are still some folders like:

```
psi4-1.3.2+ecbda83-py37h06ff01c_1, psi4-rt-1.3.2-py37h6cf1279_1
```

And the same happened for other packages that I manually identified, therefore, I assume that the same happen for the rest of the packages that belonged to this environment. And the problem is that these files take space from my disk and I really don't know how  many and what are the packages on this situation.
Is there some way to delete all these non-used folders in order to free space?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you used just removes the environment or installed package not the downloaded binary files.  You can clean those up using:

```
conda clean -a
```